# Additional class rule based on template name

Tags: content-query-web-part, xslt

I'm rendering three columns, each containing a CQWP. Each CQWP will utilize a different item template to render the contents, however, I need to add an additional class rule along-side cqwp-layout-main, according to our designer / html editor.

I know that this gets rendered in the OuterTemplate in the ContentQueryMain xsl, but I cannot seem to regulate the rendering based on template name, for exampe @Style='CaseStudies'.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add additional classes to the `cqwp-layout-main` as it's not rendered through the XSLT.

The closest you can get is the `dfwp-list` from the LevelStyle.xsl which renderes the "columns" in the Content Query Web Parts.